# Android weird NavigationView menu item background color

Tags: android, navigationview

I want to customize the menu item background drawable

so far I have the following in my `activity_main.xml`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_bg"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_txt"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_txt"/>
```

and the `nav_item_bg.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_tapped_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

`nav_item_tapped_bg.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#f00"
    android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

but the `app:itemBackground` attribute does not being respected at all

I should overridden the pressed state with my custom drawable

however when tapping the item it still have default's color hint

which makes my drawable brighter, how can disable `NavigationView`'s default menu item style?

[image]